# if I use json_encode in a function, it's deleting one array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I don't know why but json_encode output has only an array in my second example.

Here is my codes:

```
$example1 = json_encode(array("inline_keyboard" => array(array(array("text" => "Google", "url" => "http://google.com")),array(array("text" => "test", "callback_data" => "test")))));

$example2 = inkeyboard(array(array("text" => "Google", "url" => "http://google.com")),array(array("text" => "test", "callback_data" => "test")));


function inkeyboard($array){
    $keyboard   = array($array);

    $resp       = array("inline_keyboard" => $keyboard);
    $reply      = json_encode($resp);

    return $reply;
}
```

and output is like this:

**Example 1 output:**

```
 {"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"Google","url":"http:\/\/google.com"}],[{"text":"test","callback_data":"test"}]]}
```

**Example 2 output:**

```
{"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"Google","url":"http:\/\/google.com"}]]}
```

they should be same. what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With example1 you pass one array:
`["inline_keyboard" => [[["text" => "Google", "url" => "http://google.com"]],[["text" => "test", "callback_data" => "test"]]]]`

With example2, your are actually passing two arguments to the function `inkeyboard`. One of them being `[["text" => "Google", "url" => "http://google.com"]]`, the second one `[["text" => "test", "callback_data" => "test"]]`.

It would work correctly, if you change example2 to:

```
$example2 = inkeyboard(array(array("text" => "Google", "url" => "http://google.com"),array(array("text" => "test", "callback_data" => "test"))));
```

Comment: OMG, I forgot the second parameter case in the function. Arrays are confusing my head. Thank you so much.